# Trying to get an html page to appear in its entirety in iOS simulator

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, uiwebview, mobile-webkit

I have an html page that I am trying to display via a `UIWebView` inside my iOS app.  Everything is working fine, except I can't view the entire page on the screen.  I only see the top left corner, and then I have to scroll either down or to the right to view the remaining page.  I do want to point out that the image that is on the HTML page is the size of a full page, which is most likely the reason why the entire HTML page does not fit on the iOS screen.

Here is my iOS code (which is very straightforward):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"arabic" ofType:@"html"] isDirectory:NO]]];
}
```

and here is the HTML code I am trying to display:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>My Title</title>

<style type="text/css">

#container {
    position:relative;
}
#highlight {
    position:absolute;
    width:325px;
    height:55px;
    top:230px;
    left:475px;
    background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

</style>

</head>
<body>

<div id="container">
    <img src="myImage.png" />
    <div id="highlight"></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong, and what I can do to view the entire page on the screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `scalesPageToFit` property of UIWebView might be what you're looking for. According to the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html),

> If YES, the web page is scaled to fit and the user can zoom in and zoom out. If NO, user zooming is disabled.

Hope this helps!